# can I "import" React CSS modules from a string?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

I have a React project that uses CSS Modules by importing .css files.  e.g. `import styles from "./styles/MyComponent.css";`

I find myself now in a situation where a component is receiving a customized snippet of CSS as a string in response to a dynamic call to the server.

Is it possible to take this string (which is unknown until runtime) and essentially do the same thing to it that `import` does to the .css file when it is compiled by webpack?

For example:

```
import styles from "./styles/MyComponent.css";

//later on in component...
moreStyle = "a string containing valid CSS";

//do *something* here to moreStyle string to do whatever importing does to a file.

myJSX = (
  <div className={styles.someClass}>
    This div content is styled by someClass
  </div>
  <div className={moreStyle.someOtherClass}>
    This div content needs to be styled by someOtherClass, but obviously this isn't working
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Would you mind commenting what you edited so that my solution regarding how you defined your className is not misleading.

Comment: Ah yes - sorry.  I had mistakenly written quotation marks instead of curly braces around the className values.  My code uses curly braces

Comment: Try this: change your ‘className’ attribute to ‘style’. If your style is a string, then convert it to a JSON and it’ll work. If it’s already a serialized object, then you can skip the last step. If you still want className, it can be there, tho I don’t see the point other than for maybe E2E testing. Just note that styles expects an object, so depending on what you’re importing you try: styles={code} or try styles={{code}}

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import styles from "./styles/MyComponent.js";

myJSX = (
  <div style={styles.someClass}>
    This div content is styled by someClass
  </div>
  <div style={styles.someOtherClass}>
    This div content needs to be styled by someOtherClass, but obviously this isn't working
  </div>
);
```

Consider creating a serialized object, instead.

```
// Filename: MyComponentStyle.js
//Example styles
export const styles = {
  someClass: { height: 10 },
  someOtherClass: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  }
};
```

React doesn't work like your typical HTML/CSS/JS app. The thing to note that JSX may look like HTML but it is not HTML.

In your code, className is being defined as a string, which is expected, however, there's possibly no CSS being referred to in this document. Try to console.log it and see what you get.

...

Another possible solution is to simply have your style within the same component file. A common design choice for component styling is inline styling. This is especially useful for projects of medium-large scale, where managing files can get difficult.

Helpful references:

https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion to define style in a different manner, but the contents of the string `moreStyle` arrive dynamically to my component at runtime.  I don't know them beforehand, and I am hoping to be able to integrate them into the existing css by doing to them at runtime whatever it is that the compiler does at build time to css contents imported from a file